# .htaccess and HTTP_HOST

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, multisite

We have a Wordpress multisite install with sites with each having its own domain:

fantastic-training

fantastic-thinking

perceptionprofiling

In the htdocs folder we have a sub-folder with assets we are using for one of the sites and that folder is called /Aj-Isle/ the non wordpress assets should be for the https://fantastic-training.com/ site.

However the folder is available to all 3 domains which is behaviour we don’t want. So trying to look at the file DOMAIN/Aj-Isle/south.png in all 3 domains works.

https://fantastic-training.com/Aj-Isle/south.png

https://fantastic-thinking.com/Aj-Isle/south.png

https://perceptionprofiling.com/Aj-Isle/south.png

Does anybody know how can we can use the .htaccess file in the htdocs folder to restrict it so that the Aj-Isle folder is only available when the https://fantastic-training.com/ domain is requested?

I think it has something to do with the HTTP_HOST variable?

Basically I know that in English the rules I want to create are these...

If you are inbound for /Aj-Isle/ and not requesting https://fantastic-training.com/Aj-Isle/ then redirect to the root of the target domain

If you are inbound for /limesurvey/ and not requesting https://perceceptionprofiling.com/limesurvey/ then redirect to the root of the target domain

Our .htaccess file in htdocs currently looks like this...

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
AllowOverride All
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Thanks in advance for any help or insights that can be offered.
Steve H-B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the host name with a [`RewriteCond`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !fantastic-training.com
RewriteRule ^Aj-Isle / [R,L]
```

This checks, if the requested path starts with `Aj-Isle`. If it doesn't, proceed with the following rule(s).

If it does start with `Aj-Isle`, then the requested host is checked against `fantastic-training.com`. If the requested host is *not* `fantastic-training.com`, redirect the client to the root folder (`/`).

See [`RewriteCond`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) for a detailed explanation

> CondPattern is usually a perl compatible regular expression, but there is additional syntax available to perform other useful tests against the Teststring:
>
> 1. You can prefix the pattern string with a '!' character (exclamation mark) to negate the result of the condition, no matter what kind of CondPattern is used.